# Программа по работе с интернет-магазином (Java)

Tags: java, opencart, jsoup, apache-poi

Есть :

- Файл остатков в *.xls*, - в нем артикул товара, наименование, цена.
- Сайт на OpenCart (не работал с такими конструкторами, т.к. писал сайты только с нуля на чистом html).

На сайте есть около 1000 товаров, каждую неделю нужно обновлять артикулы на сайте из файла остатков.

Я пытался реализовать на Java подобный алгоритм кода :

- Парсим .xls через *POI Apache*
- Сохраняем артикулы и наименования в массив
- Пробегаем по массиву и ищем на странице админки сайта данный товар с таким же наименованием.
- Парсим его артикулы через jsoup, - если артикул разный, то из файла остатков берем артикул и присваиваем его данному товару. Проверяем.
- Идем дальше по циклу остального массива.

Есть ли более адекватное решение?

Нашел вот это API :

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=20043

http://docs.opencart.com/system/users/api/

Какой должен быть алгоритм по работе с этим движком и товарами?

Comment: Более адекватное, посмотреть есть ли у Joomla API и работать через него. Менее адекватное - посмотреть на структуру базы Joomla, найти там свои товары и изменять напрямую в базе.

Comment: @Morewind как оказалось стоит сайт на OpenCart.

Comment: @Morewind в их API разобраться не удается,так как ранее не работал с ним.

Comment: Так начните работать сейчас.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в ручную? там просто API не понятное, т.к. в сайтах разделы и т.п. 
мне нужен алгоритм как это всё делать или примерные ссылки на похожие траблы . Просто >1000 товаров это ужас же, каждому артикул менять уууу

Comment: Нет, не в ручную. Просто разберитесь в API и напишите программу его использующую. Или вы хотите, чтобы мы написали за вас?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да с API- не вариант, потому что сайт может умереть при API- изменениях. Есть вариант такой : получить доступ к БД,выгружать оттуда .xls и уже сравнивать данные с файлом остатков, потом загружать обратно в БД. Но я ищу ещё варианты. 
API - отпадает. БД - пока не буду использовать этот вариант. Вручную - муторно. Через парсер - тоже муторно. Вот хочу услышать варианты решения. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным и даст совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в **opencart'е** артикул, количество, цена товара лежат в базе данных в таблице `refix_product`, наименования в таблице `refix_product_description`, остальные данные и опции товара раскиданы по ещё **13**ти таблицам. Что бы всё сделать правильно а не оставить заказчику пахнущий код с непонятной логикой, необходимо:

**Вар.1:** написать контроллер по правилам opencart'а, который будет обрабатывать *.xls*; написать модельку по правилам opencart'а, которая будет выбирать из бд, обрабатывать в соответствии с логикой и перезаписывать в бд обновления остатков. Можно и вью набросать за ради управления этими процессами из админки.

**Вар.2:** Найти, скачать, установить и настроить модуль реализующий соответствующий функционал, благо под OC их довольно много. Большинство платные, но некоторые из них даже работают =).

Пардон за демагогию, просто сталкиваюсь с результатами таких вот подходов очень часто. Поверьте, первый же модуль или расширение (а там ещё и oc/vqModы), положит ваше API напрочь в лучшем случае, в худшем положит магазин. Если вы берёте в руки систему - работайте по правилам этой системы. Когда-нибудь вам самим придётся разбирать шлакокод за очередным шлакоделом.

Спасибо за внимание.